# Second icons in chrome.extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I have a more than one icon in one browser action ? Or create new extension ? I want a two icon and each of them to other action, first icon -> save my url (i've this one) and second to read this url from my server (this i've too) but i need second icon in one extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one icon at this moment. I would suggest two options though:

- Create a popup.html page that displays both options (save and read)
- Use a toggle action which would change your icon with `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` when you click on your browser icon.